# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error when I try to instantiate the GCS Service

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am very new to java/Android development. My IDE of choice is Android Studio. Essentially I need to upload images/vidoes clips and audio clips to GCS. I am instantiating the service like this

> " final GcsService gcsService = >GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());" 
>   When I run the app I get the following error 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty
>              at >com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService(GcsServiceFact>ory.java:40)
>              at >com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory>.java:34)
>              at >com.horcu.lme.gavi.cloud.CloudPersister.downloadDataFromGcs(CloudPersister.java:30)
>              at >com.horcu.lme.gavi.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:159)
>   
>   The dependency section of my build.gradle file looks like this
>
> dependencies {
>      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
>      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>      compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03@jar'
>     compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.3.3@jar'
>      compile 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550@jar'
>
> }

As you can see I am including the appengine-gcs-client jar file and it compiles just fine but crashes at run-time.
Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually means that you are missing dependencies.  Note that GCS requires more then just the appengine-gcs-client jar.  For one thing, I think it requires joda-time.jar.

Also, using the API's that are not available as services within app engine typically requires the Google Java client library, do you have that?
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Finally, I would note that the error you have above is for "com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty" which is actually part of app engine itself.  Do you have the app engine JAR's?  I haven't used Android Studio but I wouldn't expect you to have to add the app engine JAR's manually - when you created an app engine project that should have been added automatically.

If you aren't wed to Android Studio, you might want to consider Eclipse + ADT where all of this is done for you.  Google has said that Android STudio will support GAE, but it's not even released for Android yet, let alone app engine.

Comment: I imported my app to Eclipse and it worked like a charm. Thanks a million that saved me a whole lot of time.

Comment: I had to go back to using Android Studio and the same issue is still plagueing me. Has anyone successfully added/used the gcs-client library to an Android Studio project?