# Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library uses Unknown Dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library

```
com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.3.13
```

into a Java library project which will be used for Android (not into the Android project directly).

The library itself compiles fine, but then I run into some strange "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" errors during compile. I realized these are missing dependencies and I already figured out that Guava is one of these:

```
com.google.guava:guava:17.0
```

But now it asks for something from App Engine:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty
```

What is this? How can I find out which library is missing? Can I analyze the JAR somehow? Or do you know if this is documented somewhere?

Remember I am on the frontend, not the backend, so I can't or probably shouldn't embed app engine into Android :(

Status Update:

So far, I found out the following:

The required dependencies are these:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.3.13@jar'
```

There is **no working sample application** out there for the GCS Java Client on Android Studio, and the Java Client libraries are miserably documented. What's shown on the website is all for Eclipse and these are code-fragments, no working downloadable project: see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

The client lib distribution which is specified in that document **does not contain** com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty (the one that fails). SystemProperty **is** contained in appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.6.jar but when I place that jar into libs my machine freezes during compile with some dexer problem. [As I said earlier, we are on the client and I don't think I am supposed to do this.]

@jamrockRay had the same issue, but decided to switch to Eclipse, what supposedly solved the problem: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error when I try to instantiate the GCS Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673496/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-error-when-i-try-to-instantiate-the-gcs-service) - I have no option to switch. The failure is exactly described in that document, and my stack trace reveals the same issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:45)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:38)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(GcsServiceFactory.java:34)
```

Am I the only one who is using Cloud Storage? I can't believe so.

Google: Which are the dependencies to get the GCS Java Client working on Android Studio? And what does SystemProperty do in a client side library? What are the connections? How is my client module supposed to read out applicationId and applicationVersion [if this refers to App Engine] when this is specified in the backend module? How is this properly implemented and where is this described?

Comment: How are you building the application? And note that the class is in an `api` package, which may simply mean that it's a client Java class representing something in the Web API.

Comment: I am using Android Studio / Java 7 for the build. I have added 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.3.13@jar' from the Maven repository. Is this what you wanted to know? I am new to Android Studio and I don't know how packages are made, but I assume the JAR file contains references to further packages in case there are dependencies.

Comment: The jar contains references to other *classes* but not to any jars that contain them. A build tool such as Maven or Gradle will handle all this for you. Maven has better Eclipse integration, but either is a decent option.